# From what date should I send the invoices?

Tags: meaning

> From what date should I send the invoices?

Today this question is asked to me. But I couldn't understand if he intend the date when he will start to send or the date from which the invoices are ? What does this question exactly mean? Without any context does it have two meanings?(by the way the questioner is not a native speaker)

Comment: If he's not a native speaker, the safest way is to ask him what he means!

Comment: Does this sentence make any sense for a native speaker? What would you undetstand?

Comment: I would guess that he meant "On what date shall I start to send out the invoices?", but it's not safe to rely on a guess.

Comment: Demonstrated by the fact that Colin has guessed the other meaning!

Comment: I would think almost certainly he meant *What **Invoice Date** should I put on the bill?* Larger companies often delay payment to smaller suppliers until so many days / weeks after *Date of Invoice*. That's the date as specified on the supplier's bill, ***not*** the date on which the larger company entered the invoice into their accounting system (otherwise the big companies would just stack up unpaid bills for weeks before entering them into the accounts).

Answer (score 3):

It could mean either.

Without any context, I would assume that the date was the date of the invoices rather than the date to start sending.

If they were talking about the date to start sending, I would expect "When should I start sending the invoices", so the choice of "From what date" *probably* suggests the other meaning.

But this is a weak assumption, from knowlege of how things work in the world and how people are likely to express themselves: you cannot tell from the words alone.

Comment: Given the OP himself isn't a native Anglophone, and this looks like a transaction between two small local businesses (rather than OP dealing with a native Anglophone working in the accounts department of some primarily Anglophone global company), I'd say you're almost certainly right. An actual native Anglophone would probably ask *What date shall I put on the invoices?* (perhaps implying *Would it be okay to date the invoices as last month, and will they be settled more quickly if I do?*).

Comment: (by implication, the only problem really is the speaker used the wrong initial preposition: ***With** what date shall I send the invoices?*)

Comment: I think you're right, @FumbleFingers, and that's actually a third reading I hadn't thought of. I was interpreting as "I'm going to send you some (existing) invoices. At what invoice date do you want me to start?" But your interpretation is more likely.

Comment: I hadn't noticed *questioner is not a native speaker* at the end of OP's question text when I made those comments. I'd already *guessed* the utterance didn't come from a native speaker, but now I know that for sure I'm even more convinced that it's just a "sub-optimal" initial preposition being used for an extremely common context (self-employed / small businessman asking what date to put on the invoice to encourage prompt payment).